# Silverlight calling 3rd party web service. How to avoid cross-domain issues?

Tags: web-services, silverlight

Well. I created reference, tested on local machine all is well. Deployed solution to production server and here we go:

> An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI
>
> This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain
>   way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a po

From what I gathered - it's security measure to prevent something (not sure what). Well. I can't make provider to put clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml.

What is my options? Looks like either running Silverlight app in elevated mode or.. ?
I don't want to require elevated trust.

The only way I know is to call my server and make call to webservice from my server returning data back to client. Seems like too much overhead. Is there any better way? Really frustrating.

Comment: It's a [security measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) to prevent automatic cross-domain API calls. There's a nice explanation [here](http://www.devtoolshed.com/explanation-cross-domain-and-client-access-policy-files-silverlight)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid your options are limited here. In compliance with [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) the cross domain policy file is a must. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlightws/archive/2008/03/30/some-tips-on-cross-domain-calls.aspx) you can find an example why. Personally I would go down the route of proxying the remote web service via your hosting server if you can't influence the provider.